# Log HTTP requests with NLog

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-web-api, nlog

How to log **HTTP Requests** completely with **NLog**?

Here is how **[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)** catches it and I need something like this:

```
POST http://localhost/api/places/add HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Authorization: 375DF933413
Content-Length: 78
Content-Type: application/json

{ "location": { "lon": 35.005577, "lat": 48.435533}, "name": "n1" }
```

I believe it should be possible to write some "magic" NLog layout expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using an `ActionFilterAttribute` to achieve something similar:

```
public class LogHttpRequest : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(request.RequestType + " " + request.Url + "\n");

        var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.Headers.ToString());

        foreach (string key in parsed)
        {
            sb.Append(key + ": " + parsed[key] + "\n");
        }

        var inputStream = request.InputStream;
        inputStream.Position = 0;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            sb.Append("\n" + body);
        }

        _log.Log(LogLevel.Info, sb.ToString());

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to use an NLog layout expression, you could do something like this in the `ActionFilter`:

```
var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, null, null);
var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.Headers.ToString());

foreach (string key in parsed)
{
    logEventInfo.Properties.Add(key, parsed[key]);
}

var inputStream = request.InputStream;
inputStream.Position = 0;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
{
    var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    logEventInfo.Properties.Add("Body", body);
}

_log.Log(logEventInfo);
```

And then in your NLog layout, you could access these properties with
`${event-context:item=Key}` where Key is the name of the name of the header you want to include in the output.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach:

```
public class LogHttpRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _logger.Debug("action executing");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LogHttpRequestAttribute ());


}
```

To log the URL, use for  `${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}` in you config, See [wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers#nlogweb-package-). Install NLog.Web for those layout renderers.

See [NLog Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Log-HTTP-calls)